# Raspberry Pi 4 missing reverse ticks from AB encoder

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am writing a program to control a robot in C using a raspberry pi, but for some reason, I am consistently missing reverse encoder steps. CW is positive, CCW is negative. When the wheel completes a cycle (1 rot CW, 1 rot CCW) the encoder ends up with hundreds of positive ticks left when it should be zero.

Setup:

- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
- 2x Brushed DC motor with encoder. [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DKJT2XF)

  - 5v power from regulator
  - Encoder Right A: GPIO 19
  - Encoder Right B: GPIO 21
  - Encoder Left A: GPIO 11
  - Encoder Left B: GPIO 13
- Motor controller L298N to power the motor.

  - Left Enable (speed control): GPIO pin 12 (PWM 0)
  - Right Enable (speed control): GPIO pin 35 (PWM 1)
  - Left Forward: GPIO pin 24
  - Left Reverse: GPIO pin 22
  - Right Forward: GPIO pin 26
  - Right Reverse: GPIO pin 18

Here is the confusing part. I measured the top speed of the motor, and it is able to do 10 rotations in ~12 seconds (0.833 rot/sec). And based on documentation from a very similar motor by servo-city (which I tested and found to be applicable to this motor), there are ~3575.0855 ticks per rotation. This means I need to be able to read 2979.2379 ticks per second. ~3000Hz (335 us between edges, worst case) does not seem unreasonable.

I used the Realtime library provided [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=228727) to measure the execution time. With optimizations, I am able to get the loop time below a max of 50 us, which should be more than enough to catch the edge changes. My question is, why might this not be working, and what should I try to fix it?

test.c

```
// g++ -o test test.c Realtime.cc -lm -lbcm2835

#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "Realtime.h"

#define MOTOR_L_R RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_22
#define MOTOR_L_F RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_24
#define MOTOR_R_F RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_26
#define MOTOR_R_R RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_18

#define MOTOR_PWM_L RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_12
#define MOTOR_PWM_R RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_35

#define LIGHT_L RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_03
#define LIGHT_R RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_05

#define ENCODER_R_A RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_19
#define ENCODER_R_B RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_21
#define ENCODER_L_A RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_11
#define ENCODER_L_B RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_13

#define TICKS_PER_REV 3575.0855;
#define TICKS_PER_RAD 568.99252930116018242497;


void setup_terminal()
{
    struct termios term;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);
}

char read_keyboard_input()
{
    char c;
    read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // Set the terminal to take inputs immediately, without waiting for [ENTER]
    setup_terminal();
    if (!bcm2835_init())
        return 1;

    int flags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    // Configure the two PWM ports that control the speed of the wheels
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(MOTOR_PWM_L, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_ALT5); // PWM0
    bcm2835_pwm_set_mode(0, 1, 1);                                // mark-space mode
    bcm2835_pwm_set_range(0, 1024);                               // 10-bit range
    bcm2835_pwm_set_clock(BCM2835_PWM_CLOCK_DIVIDER_16);          // 16 prescaler
    bcm2835_pwm_set_data(0, 1023);

    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(MOTOR_PWM_R, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_ALT5); // PWM0
    bcm2835_pwm_set_mode(1, 1, 1);                                // mark-space mode
    bcm2835_pwm_set_range(1, 1024);                               // 10-bit range
    bcm2835_pwm_set_clock(BCM2835_PWM_CLOCK_DIVIDER_16);          // 16 prescaler
    bcm2835_pwm_set_data(1, 1023);

    // Set the motors as outputs
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(MOTOR_L_R, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(MOTOR_L_F, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(MOTOR_R_F, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(MOTOR_R_R, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);

    // Set the lights as outputs
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(LIGHT_L, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(LIGHT_R, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);

    bcm2835_gpio_write(LIGHT_L, LOW);
    bcm2835_gpio_write(LIGHT_R, LOW);

    // Set the encoders as inputs
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(ENCODER_L_A, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(ENCODER_L_B, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);
    bcm2835_gpio_set_pud(ENCODER_L_A, BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_UP);
    bcm2835_gpio_set_pud(ENCODER_L_B, BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_UP);

    uint8_t encoder_l_a = bcm2835_gpio_lev(ENCODER_L_A);
    uint8_t encoder_l_b = bcm2835_gpio_lev(ENCODER_L_B);
    int max_delay = 0;
    int last_change = -1;
    int c;
    int num_ticks = 0;
    Realtime::setup();
    uint32_t begin = Realtime::micros();
    uint32_t end = Realtime::micros();
    while (1)
    {
        // CW is positive ticks
        uint8_t encoder_l_a_new = bcm2835_gpio_lev(ENCODER_L_A);
        uint8_t encoder_l_b_new = bcm2835_gpio_lev(ENCODER_L_B);
        if(encoder_l_a_new != encoder_l_a)
        {
            if(encoder_l_a > encoder_l_a_new) // high to low
            {
                if(encoder_l_b)
                {
                    // printf("L\n");
                    num_ticks--;
                }
                else
                {
                    // printf("R\n");
                    num_ticks++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(encoder_l_b)
                {
                    // printf("R\n");
                    num_ticks++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // printf("L\n");
                    num_ticks--;
                }
            }
            // printf("A\n");
            encoder_l_a = encoder_l_a_new;
            if(last_change == 1)
            {
                // num_ticks++;
            }
            last_change = 0;
            
            if(num_ticks ==0)
            {
                printf("%d\n",num_ticks);
            }
        }
        if(encoder_l_b_new != encoder_l_b)
        {
            if(encoder_l_b > encoder_l_b_new) // high to low
            {
                if(encoder_l_a)
                {
                    // printf("R\n");
                    num_ticks++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // printf("L\n");
                    num_ticks--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(encoder_l_a)
                {
                    // printf("L\n");
                    num_ticks--;
                }
                else
                {
                    // printf("R\n");
                    num_ticks++;
                }
            }
            // printf("B\n");
            encoder_l_b = encoder_l_b_new;
            if(last_change == 0)
            {
                // num_ticks++;
            }
            last_change = 1;
            if(num_ticks ==0)
            {
                printf("%d\n",num_ticks);
            }
        }



        end = Realtime::micros();
        if(end-begin > max_delay)
        {
            max_delay = end-begin;
            printf("d:%d\n",max_delay);
        }
        begin = Realtime::micros();

    }
    bcm2835_close();
    return 0;
}
```

Realtime.cc

```
//  Realtime.cc
/*
    Copyright 2018 by Tom Roberts. All rights reserved.
    This code may be redistributed in accordance with the 
    Gnu Public License: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <sched.h>

#include "Realtime.h"

volatile uint32_t *Realtime::systReg = 0;
int Realtime::fdMem = -1;
uint32_t Realtime::phys = 0;

void Realtime::setup()
{
    initMicros();
    disableTurbo();
    realTimeSched();
    cpu3();
}

void Realtime::initMicros()
{
    // based on pigpio source; simplified and re-arranged
    fdMem = open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    if(fdMem < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot map memory (need sudo?)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // figure out the address
    FILE *f = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo","r");
    char buf[1024];
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),f); // skip first line
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),f); // model name

    // if(strstr(buf,"ARMv6")) {
    //  phys = 0x20000000;
    // } else if(strstr(buf,"ARMv7")) {
    //  phys = 0x3F000000;
    // } else if(strstr(buf,"ARMv8")) {
    //  phys = 0x3F000000;
    // } else {
    //  fprintf(stderr,"Unknown CPU type\n");
    //  exit(1);
    // }
    phys = 0xFE000000; // For raspberry pi 4
    fclose(f);
    systReg = (uint32_t *)mmap(0,0x1000,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                MAP_SHARED|MAP_LOCKED,fdMem,phys+0x3000);
}

void Realtime::delay(int us)
{
    // The final microsecond can be short; don't let the delay be short.
    ++us;

    // usleep() on its own gives latencies 20-40 us; this combination
    // gives < 25 us.
    uint32_t start = micros();
    if(us >= 100)
        usleep(us - 50);
    while(micros()-start < us)
        ;
}

void Realtime::disableTurbo()
{
    // This fixes the CPU clock to its minimum value, so timing is
    // not screwed up by changing it; also keep the SPI clock correct.
    system("sudo cp /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq "
        "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq");
}

void Realtime::enableTurbo()
{
    system("sudo cp /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq "
        "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq");
}

void Realtime::realTimeSched()
{
    int prio = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
    struct sched_param param;
    param.sched_priority = prio;
    sched_setscheduler(0,SCHED_FIFO,&param);
    // This permits realtime processes to use 100% of a CPU, but on a
    // RPi that starves the kernel. Without this there are latencies
    // up to 50 MILLISECONDS.
    system("echo -1 >/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us");
}

void Realtime::cpu3()
{
    // this does nothing if there are fewer than 4 CPUs
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(3,&cpuset);
    sched_setaffinity(0,sizeof(cpu_set_t),&cpuset);
}

void Realtime::cpu2()
{
    // this does nothing if there are fewer than 4 CPUs
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(2,&cpuset);
    sched_setaffinity(0,sizeof(cpu_set_t),&cpuset);
}

#ifdef TEST_REALTIME

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Realtime::setup();
    printf("Realtime mode setup, here's a shell on CPU3\n");
    system("/bin/bash -i");
    return 0;
}

#endif //TEST_REALTIME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It turns out the encoders on the motors I bought are bad and their a/b signals overlap such that I can't extract useful data about the rotations. I've attached some images from an oscilloscope to show what I mean.

To confirm my theory, I wrote some code to test the encoders using an Arduino nano and experienced the exact same behavior.[image: Image showing 0.0us delay]
[image: Image showing 100us delay]